# Execute the content of a second file in the first

Tags: ruby, twitter

I have a question, as I can edit this code to "twit" in a ruby file to send...

would be better that everything can be done from a file... but I can not do it :(

From already thank you very much! and this is my first post, if I mistake apology. I always read but now I can not find a twitter for ruby updated :(

```
require 'Twitter'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "xxxx"
  config.consumer_secret = "xxxx"
  config.access_token = "xxxx"
  config.access_token_secret = "xxxx"
end

file = File.open("scrapy.rb")
ary = []
i = 0
file.each_line do |line|
  ary[i] = line.chomp
  i += 1
end
file.close

j = 0

i.times do
  client.update("#{ary[j]}")
  j += 1
  sleep 10
end
```

My scrapy

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


page = Nokogiri::XML(open('xxxxxxxxxxxx'))

eventos= page.xpath("//item")

eventos.each do |e|
ubicacion = e.xpath "title"
magnitud = e.xpath "emsc:magnitude"
horaUTC = e.xpath("emsc:time").text.split(" ",2).last
depth = e.xpath "emsc:depth"
link =  e.xpath "guid"
puts [ubicacion, magnitud, horaUTC, depth, link].join "|" 
end
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run your "scrapy.rb" using the first script? :)

Comment: In conclusion, I want to send the result of the scrapy to twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
file = File.open("scrapy.rb")
```

simply require or load the other file

```
load 'scrapy'
```

Even better, you can convert the content of `scrapy` in a function, require the file once at the top of the first file, and call the function where you need it.

Comment: He hands me some errors...

But how could implement the twitter at the same code from the "scrapy.rb".

(Another way without damaging the "scrapy")

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, I refactored the code a bit:

```
require 'Twitter'
require 'open3'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "xxxx"
  config.consumer_secret = "xxxx"
  config.access_token = "xxxx"
  config.access_token_secret = "xxxx"
end

cmd = 'ruby scrapy.rb'
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout|
  file = stdout.read
  ary = []
  file.each_line do |line|
    ary << line.chomp
  end
  ary.each do |line|
    client.update(line)
    sleep 10
  end
end
```

Comment: He hands me some errors...

But how could implement the twitter at the same code from the "scrapy.rb".

(Another way without damaging the "scrapy")

Comment: can you post the error? Actually, its not `scrapy` thats being modified, but your `tweeter` script rather :)

Comment: twitter.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
twitter.rb:12:in `load': cannot load such file -- scrapy (LoadError)
        from twitter.rb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: It appears there's something wrong with your "scrapy" script. Have you verified the xml file you're trying to parse valid? Can you try to run your `scrapy.rb` and check if it has no errors and has an output?

Comment: The "Scrapy" works perfectly... Only that I now want to post data to twitter and have no knowledge on twitter, the twitter script api is a subject of this website.

Comment: Is your `scrapy.rb` in the same directory as your twitter script? If not, kindly put the correct path for your scrapy.rb . If it still doesn't work, I'll edit the code to use another method :)

Comment: Yes, It is located in the same directory. But that method could use? I do not know the twitter api.

Comment: Have you tried to run the above code? Even if you don't know the Twitter API, you could just do trial and error to learn it :) Post the errors if you see any.

Comment: Yes, it was proven and also wrote the error code in the last post.

Comment: I mean, I edited the code and want to know if you tried the new solution using open3...

Comment: Open3?What means "open3"?

Comment: Its a ruby class Eduardo. You can use it to run your scrapy script and it will get the output of it so you can use it for your twitter script :)

Comment: I was reading something. But apparently I'm slow lol thank you very much for the help...

I will keep looking for :)